# How to convert from DIV with two images within to image by html2canvas

Tags: html, html2canvas

I have a simple div with two images within it and I need to render it to a new image by html2canvas library. Both images are in PNG in order to overlap them, and actually it is working on the template, but after I cannot render it as a single image by html2canvas.

The html2canvas library it is working in my project and in fact I am using it succesfully in other parts of it.

Basically the code is:

Template (HTML)

```
<div #imagePreview>
      <img src="../image1.png" />
      <img src="../image2.png" />
</div>
```

Controller (Typescript)

```
@ViewChild('imagePreview', { static: false }) imagePreview: ElementRef;

html2canvas(this.imagePreview).then(canvas => {
      const myImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      window.open(myImage)
    });
```

Expected: Render a single image with the two images of the div overlaped

The current output: A white image

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tested it and it is working like a charm :
index.php file code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="html2canvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #F0F0F1; color: #00cc65; 
 width: 500px;padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <img src="http://www.astrojpshiv.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Logo.png" 
 style="width:100%;display: inline-block;"/>
        <strong>Text Heading</strong><hr/>
        <h5 style="color: #3e4b51;">
            Find Here Design And Development | Gopal Sharma
        </h5>
        <p style="color: #3e4b51;">
            <b>Gopal Sharma</b> is a web developer.
        </p>
        <center><img src="https://www.letscontrolit.com/wiki/images/d/df/User-Demo- 
    Demo.png" style="display: inline-block;"/><br/><?php
        $timezone = 'Asia/Calcutta';
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
        echo date("D-m-Y H:i:s A"); ?></center>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>
    <script src="download_image_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

hmtl2canvas library code used by me : save this library's code as html2canvas.js `

https://bitbucket.baseline.info/users/orane/repos/basedrive-ey/browse/app/www/client/plugins/html2canvas.js?until=e018fa46a940f04e018a7c929b5af73eab44ef0d&untilPath=app%2Fwww%2Fclient%2Fplugins%2Fhtml2canvas.js&at=aae479c69d8e96101cb605d3ac669b0b52cd48c5

Combined-Image file will automatically download with the name "your_pic_name-55.png" and here is your last '.js' file include before closing body-tag save below code as "download_image_file.js"

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 * Gopal Sharma | Web Developer
 */


$(document).ready(function(){
var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").click();
             }
         });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet- 
 stream");
    var filename = 'your_pic_name-55.png';
    $("<a download='" + filename + "' href='" + newData + "'></a>")[0].click(); 
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").click();
});
```